# Tomcat 7 ROOT.war in webapps worked for a couple days now a blank page

Tags: grails, openshift

I published my ROOT.war to the Openshit Tomcat7 free service. After rhc commit and push the web application was running great for a couple days. Then all of the sudden it will only display a blank page. I've tried 'rhc app restart' from terminal without success. The other day, the only way I could overcome this was to delete the application from Openshift console and recreate the gear.

Any tips on troubleshooting? thanks

jbossews-2.0 (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0))

> [map-whcw.rhcloud.com logs]> grep -i error jbossews.log
>
> 2015-11-23 12:36:58,072 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>
> 2015-11-23 12:36:58,075 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>
> 2015-11-23 17:05:59,468 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>
> 2015-11-23 17:05:59,560 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>
> 2015-11-24 07:11:43,964 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>
> 2015-11-24 07:11:43,967 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: auth.User
>   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
>   INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

Comment: The log tail does not say what happened there. Maybe you can ssh into your app and check for any clues in the logs in `~/app-root/logs/`.

Comment: @JiriFiala, thanks for info. I just posted a log file that was in the app-root/logs/ directory. Does this make any sense?

Comment: This error is not familiar to me, but you may want to try `rhc app force-stop <yourApp>` and `rhc app start <yourApp>` whether the effect is the same as recreating the app. Also, you can check for memory issues on OpenShift (https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues) and the disk quota usage, given the described behavior (runs for some time, then needs to be re-created).